# Flutter- Firestore Bloc

Tags: flutter

I would like to know how to implement `Bloc` pattern for `Firestore`.
When applying `Bloc` for increment app from flutter default app, would look like this.

```
class IncrementBloc implements BlocBase {

  int _counter;


  StreamController<int> _counterController = StreamController<int>();
  StreamSink<int> get _inAdd => _counterController.sink;
  Stream<int> get outCounter => _counterController.stream;


  StreamController<int> _actionController = StreamController<int>();
  StreamSink<int> get incrementCounter => _actionController.sink;

  IncrementBloc() {
    _counter = 0;
    _actionController.stream.listen(_handleLogic);
  }

  void _handleLogic(data) {
    _counter += 1;
    _inAdd.add(_counter);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _counterController.close();
    _actionController.close();
  }
}
```

The question is how to implement this logic for `Firestore`.
For example, if I want to update badge value when user get a new follower, I have to listen for new creation of `Firestore` document. But I don't know how to create `Bloc` `Firestore` version that cover these things and I couldn't find it.
How can I listen for that in `Bloc`
Does anyone tell me how to create it?

Comment: You can definetly use a StreamBuilder widget listening to `Firestore.instance.collection('example').snapshots()`. It listens to any changes on the collection and runs a builder function that returns a widget.
If this is useful for you I can detail it in an answer, or you are limited to using BLoC?

Comment: Thank you for comment. But that will update only when user on that page. I want to update tab bar badge value even if user is on different page. Do you know how to?

Comment: Is the badge visible on screen all the time? Can you post an example or an image of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Every time new document create, I want to update bottom nav  badge value number.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this below should work for you, just add the listener on the page you want to show that value

```
class IncrementBloc implements BlocBase {

  int _counter;

  StreamController<int> _counterController = StreamController<int>();
  StreamSink<int> get _inAdd => _counterController.sink;
  Stream<int> get outCounter => _counterController.stream;


  StreamController<int> _actionController = StreamController<int>();
  StreamSink<int> get incrementCounter => _actionController.sink;

  IncrementBloc() {
    // Get the latest value from firebase and listen to stream
    countAPI.getNumber().then(number) {
      _counter = number;
      _inAdd(_counter);
    });
    _actionController.stream.listen(_handleLogic);
  }

  void _handleLogic(data) async {
    _counter += 1;
    await countAPI.updateNumber(_counter); // this updates firebase
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _counterController.close();
    _actionController.close();
  }
}

class APIs {
  Future<int> getNumber() async {
    try {
      // Get number from firebase
    } catch (e) {
      // Error
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateNumber() async {
    // Firebase upload 
  }
}

APIs countAPI = APIs();
```